# Modifiers on %a specifier?

Tags: formatting, ocaml

After consulting the [Format](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Format.html) and [Printf](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Printf.html) module documentation, I'm still left with an unanswered question about the `%a` specifier.

Starting with a very simple type:

```
type b = C of float
```

I can easily create a printing routine:

```
let pp ppf (C f) = 
  Format.fprintf ppf "%.2f" f
```

Such that `Format.asprintf "%a" pp (C 7.6)` yields `"7.60"`.

Now, `Format.asprintf "%.3a" pp (C 7.6)` runs without issue, but of course I still get `"7.60"`.

Is there a way to access the modifier within `pp` to determine the precision to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%a` specifier does not accept any flag, padding or width arguments.
Historically, the interpretation of the specifier was lax and silently ignored any such arguments

```ml
Format.printf "%0.3a"
```

However, enabling `-strict-formats` make the compiler reject this erroneous format string with

> Error: invalid format "%0.3a": at character number 0, `padding' is incompatible with 'a' in sub-format "%0.3a"

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question, as @octachron's already covered, is essentially "no". But you can still alter the precision of your `pp` function by adding a precision argument to it and using the `.*` precision specifier instead:

```
let pp precision ppf (C f) = 
  Format.fprintf ppf "%.*f" precision f
```

```
Format.asprintf "%a" (pp 2) (C 7.6);; (* prints 7.60 *)
Format.asprintf "%a" (pp 3) (C 7.6);; (* prints 7.600 *)
```